# How do I find the separator of elements in a string?

Tags: regex, string, algorithm

I have a string such as "option1;option2;option3" where the ";" separator might be anything. Any string of at least 1 character that the user puts.

I am looking for a simple/clean way to determine the separator without any information other than the input string.

I can guarantee the separator exists only between 2 elements but consider the possibility of only one option in the input string. I can also guarantee that the separator will only be non alphanumerical and may contain space and $ or # or % etc.

Couldn't create a regular expression for this, but perhaps someone will be able to, though I am not particularly looking for a regex expression.

Comment: What would the separator in `hello world; goodbye world` be?

Comment: Are there any non-alphanumerical characters in the string apart from the separators?

Comment: " the separator exists only between 2 elements" this is not very helpful information. It's hard for something to be **between** more than 2 or less than 2 elements in a string. Your problem is ill-posed.

Comment: @Jon it would be "; "

Comment: @Discipol: And the unasked question is: *how can you tell*? Why would it not be just `;` or just a space? What about `hello world;goodbye world`? Is it `;` or space here? Again, how can you tell?

Comment: @BartoszKP you won't have it "option1;option2;" Something can be not between 2 elements.

Comment: @Discipol It's not between anything, don't have to count the elements. But I see your point, this constraint seems ok. Nevertheless Dukeling's issue still proves that there is an unsolvable ambiguity here since you allow "space" to be a separator.

Comment: @Jon its space AND characters like #@$!

Comment: @Discipol Perhaps improve the question, "may contain space and ..." can also be interpreted as "may contain space, and may contain other characters".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the seperator

```
in = "option1;option2;option3"
separator=re.search("[ ;'#/.,<>?~@;,:}{\]\[+=\-_]+", in).group()
```

Sorry it was easier to use regexp for this

Now it's back to you.  You need to prove that this works as you intend against all possible inputs

Here's a perhaps easier to use version

```
possible=""" ;'#/.,<>?~@,:}{][+=-_"""
seperator=re.search("[%s]+" % re.escape(possible), input).group()
```

This means that characters with special meaning in regexp can be added or taken away easier

Comment: well not all possible inputs, just the most common users will input. giving an user a "bad input" error is just like saying "you suck at computers" and need this to take care of such things. A user will most likely use , or ; or "; " or ", "

Answer (score 1):

This would work only if you knew for certain that only characters [A-Za-z0-9_] would appear inf fields:
`^(\w+)\W(\w+)\W(\w+)$`

This is probably not the case, so my solution would be to:

1. Create a list of all possible separators.
2. For each of these separators run a regex (dynamically constructed in a loop): `^([^X]+)X([^X]+)X([^X]+)$` where `X` is a separator character.
3. Check if number of matches equals expected number of columns (or go to 4. if you don't know the number of columns).
4. Run it for every line to see if number of matches changes, because a match in first line could be a blind luck.
5. If it matches everywhere, then you have your separator and the number of columns. If it doesn't match then start checking next separator for every line.

The downside of this solution is that in worst case you'd run your regex for every line of text and for every separator. 
Possible optimizations would be to:

1. Start checking with most common separators first
2. Instead of running regex for every line for every separator, just count the number of separator characters in entire text. If the number of lines divides the number of separator characters without a remainder, then there's high probability that the separator is valid.